# Get URL From WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I was wondering if there exits another effective way to get the URL that will load up on the WebView. My current code gives the current Url and not the one that will be loaded.

For example if my WebView load this: **`http://stackoverflow.com`**

After loading If I click on **Questions**, I would not get this url **http://stackoverflow.com/questions**, for some reason I would get **`http://stackoverflow.com`**

So my question is **how would you get the url that will be loading on a WebView?**

This is my code, please help!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Declaring
    WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // Loading
        browser.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");


        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }

            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

                //here I get the Url, but its not accurate. Sometimes it works, sometiems it doesn't 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), browser.getUrl(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }


        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the url parameter passed into the `onLoadResource`?

Comment: Do you mean this code? 'browser.getUrl()' if not please show me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to get url from this function :

**EDIT:**

```
        browser.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                Log.v("TEST", url);
                if(url.equals("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SKIP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                   view.loadUrl(url); 
                }                 
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Reference :

[shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This would give me the current URL and not the one that is going to load up.

Comment: @Ammar as per reference it should work. [ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29 ]

Comment: Please try my code and see for yourself that it will not work. It always toast me the current url.

Comment: I don't want to find the URL after the page finished loading. I want to find the URL that will load before it starts loading. I am getting somewhere though, but so far its not working!

Comment: @Ammar I just test with your code. see my edit for that. I am able to get changed url there. I am able to take action before url load.

Comment: I take my hat off for you. Its working now, I appreciate it so much!

Comment: Hi @PratikSharma what about url changes through ajax? `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` will not be called. Can you please tell me how to detect url changes through ajax?

Comment: this was really help full to me!

Answer (score 1):

I know its very late but,for other users if it helps it would be my pleasure.
In ur WebViewClient u can use :

```css
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         
            String webUrl=view.getUrl();
            return true;
        }
    }
```